# How do you generate a random number in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been trying to generate a random number from 0 to 29. I've tried different methods from different sources to no avail.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+generate+random+number

Comment: What have you tried? What happened?

Comment: Taran, step one in figuring out coding questions is to do a google. I did a google of "c++ generate random number" and caught a bunch of good answers. This would have been MUCH faster than leaving questions here, especially as you're going to get a lot of people pointing you to the existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

To generate random numbers in c++ you will neeed to include the `<stdlib.h>` library.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Start by intialising a seed. In this example we will use the system time (`<time.h>` library) as a way to get a random seed initializer:

```
srand (time(NULL));
```

Now we create an integer variable:

```
int rNumber;
```

Finally we store the random generated number in the rNumber variable:

```
rNumber = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

Note that `% 10 + 1` means that the generated random number will be between 1 and 10.

For more in formation on random number generation and a more in depth example refer to: 
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/rand/

Comment: Please don't recommend C solutions for C++ questions especially if there are better C++ answers.